# How can one use pointer constants to point to a specific memory address (e.g. an address like 0x0001a00) in ANSI C?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I am experimenting with pointers in C programming for a project and was looking to get some guidance on whether there are other ways to initialize a pointer constant to the memory address 0x0001a000.

The following was my approach:

```
volatile int *firstAddress = (volatile int *)0x0001a000; 
printf("First Memory address is: %p\n", firstAddress);
```

Are there shorter ways to initialize the above in C programming?

Comment: Better how, in which way(s)?

Comment: Shorter ways of initialization, for aesthetics. I just felt the above was a bit too long.

Comment: It is fine that way (presuming your C implementation supports accessing that hard-coded address). If you are working with projects that need that sort of access, you will become accustomed to the pointer cast, and there is no value in seeking a textually shorter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how you would initialize such a constant, however the results are *very* implementation specific.

If the given address isn't one explicitly documented as valid, you'll likely invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You also can't really make it any more concise than this.  Conversions between integers and pointers requires a cast.

Comment: I am wondering if it is strictly UB even if the address is defined to be some hardware register? I mean it does not contain a valid "object" from C perspective. Also what will happen to pointer arithmetic on such a pointer?

Comment: @EugeneSh. An implementation may decide to define certain behaviors that the standard doesn't. My guess is that the implementation in question takes a more "portable assembler" approach to the language.  That would make supercat happy. :)